# Access all firebase user's information

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am creating an app similar to Instagram. I created a logged in user feed tab with this code

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

  let key = snapshot.key
    let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "uid")
    print(snapshot)
    if(key == self.loggedUser?.uid)
    {
        print("same as logged in user")
    }
    else
    {
    self.usersArray.append(snapshot)
         self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }



    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

However, I want to create a tab that outputs all the users in the database posts, but when I use this code

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
```

It doesn't work.

My **Firebase** database looks like this

[image]

Is there a way I can access the title node of all the users and not only the logged in users.

Comment: Please include the code within the observe completion handler (everything after `with: {`)

Comment: @dstepan I have updated it.

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The answer can be found with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730959/swift-showing-posts-from-all-firebase-users

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {

        if let item = child as? FIRDataSnapshot {

            // get values
            let foo = item["index"] as? String

        }

    }
}
```